# Is it possible some devices don't support text shadow?

Tags: android, css, sony-xperia

I've written the next simple XML , and it showed a clear text shadow on most of the devices.

However, on the [ST26i‎ device (xperia J)](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_xperia_j-4930.php) , it didn't show any shadow.

The device has Android version 4.0.4, yet the app worked fine even on an emulator with Android version 2.3 .

I've chosen very clear colors to show whether there is a shadow or not.

My question: could it be that some devices don't support text shadow? If so, what can be done?

The layout xml is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFff0000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shadowColor="#FF00FF00"
        android:shadowDx="10"
        android:shadowDy="10"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="#FF0000ff"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```